# Flow meter using Wemos Mini - ISR not in IRAM!

Tags: isr

I'm trying to use a flow meter with Wemos Mini.
Most tutorials are using Arduino boards ( which code and HW work OK ), but since I want this device to send alerts over the internet when abnormal usage/leakage is detected, I want to use Wemos Mini using [How to Use Water Flow Sensor - Arduino Tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-Water-Flow-Sensor-Arduino-Tutorial/). On top of if will add my code for notifications using Telegram.

BUT - after uploading the original code (before adding Telegram changes ), an error occurs during code run : `ISR not in IRAM!`

I tried to change Pin - but still getting this error,

Comment: Hve you seen [this issue on github](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/6127)? They state, that you can avoid this error by prepending `ICACHE_RAM_ATTR` to ISR functions. Maybe you can try this.

Comment: this is an error in the original code and new versions of core check if the ISR handler is in IRAM, because without ICACHE_RAM_ATTR  the handler sometimes worked and sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of conflicts between Serial and external interrupts
Put ICACHE_RAM_ATTR before your interrupt function, like this  `ICACHE_RAM_ATTR void ISR()`

Answer (score -1):

For WEMOS or NODEMCU you must predefine  interupt routine for example

**void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR ServiceLimitSwitchUpperShield_12_D6();**

//it is solve problem for ATTACHINTERRUPT - you must predefine this method **before use setup (very important )**
Then this message error ISR not IRAM will be not displayed .

In a setup you can for example define
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(12), **ServiceLimitSwitchUpperShield_12_D6** , FALLING );

Look for page
https://community.blynk.cc/t/error-isr-not-in-iram/37426/23

Comment: this is not true